# AngularJS - Form Validation in a templateUrl of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, directive

I am trying to use angular's form validation from inside a templateUrl.

I have a directive that loads a templateUrl in which i have a form with inputs that get ng-required and ng-regex values from directive scope. Now, i tried to put in my directive's scope 
form: '=', but when i access scope.form it is undefined.

I must specify that my submit button is outside of the form, and when clicked ng-click='save($index)' it must first check that the form is valid and then proceed with saving the edited data. scope.save() is defined in my directive.

this is from template:

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="row in source.data "  data-ng-class="{'selected':row.$_selected}" >
            <td data-ng-repeat="c in settings.columns" data-ng-click="toggleSelect(row)" >         
                <form name="editForm" id="editForm" novalidate> 
                    <div ng-switch on="c.type" ng-show="editMode[$parent.$index]">
                        <span ng-switch-when="text" >
                            <input type="{{c.type}}"  data-ng-model="row[c.name]" ng-required="{{c.isRequired}}" ng-pattern="{{c.regex}}"/>
                        </span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="select" >
                            <select  data-ng-model="row[c.name]" ng-selected="row[c.name]" ng-init="row[c.name]" ng-options="item.value as item.name for  item in c.items" ng-required="{{c.isRequired}}">
                                <!--<option data-ng-repeat="(value, name) in c.items" value="{{value}}">{{name}}</option>-->
                            </select>
                        </span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="textarea">
                            <textarea  ng-model="row[c.name]" ng-required="{{c.isRequired}}" ng-pattern="{{c.regex}}">                                                      
                            </textarea>
                        </span>
                        <span ng-switch-when="checkbox">
                            <!--<label for="checkboxInput">{{c.name}}</label>-->
                            <input name="checkboxInput" type="checkbox" data-ng-model="row[c.name]" ng-true-value="{{c.true}}" ng-false-value="{{c.false}}"/>
                        </span>
                        <span ng-switch-default="">
                            {{row[c.name]}}
                        </span>                     
                    </div>          
                </form>         
                <span ng-hide='editMode[$parent.$index]'>{{row[c.name]}}</span>
            </td>                  
            <td>
                <a href="{{row[settings.specialFields.url]}}" class="btn btn-default opacity75" data-ng-if="row[settings.specialFields.url]">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>                                      
            </td>                
            <td data-ng-if="row[settings.specialFields.isEditable]">
                <button ng-click="edit(row)" ng-show="!editMode[$index]" class="btn btn-primary" >
                    edit {{$index}}
                </button>                   
                <button ng-click="save($index)" ng-disabled=""  ng-show="editMode[$index]" class="btn btn-primary">
                    save
                </button>
                <button ng-click="cancel($index)" ng-show="editMode[$index]"  class="btn btn-default">
                    cancel
                </button>                     
            </td> 
        </tr>
```

and this is from my directive:

```
scope: {
        settings: '=',
        source: '=',
        form: '='

    },

    templateUrl: function (element, attr) {
        return attr.templateUrl || 'src/grid.html';
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.editMode = [];     

        scope.editing = false;
        scope.previousData = {};

        scope.edit = function(field) { 

            scope.editing = scope.source.data.indexOf(field);               
            scope.editMode[scope.editing] = true;               
            scope.previousData = angular.copy(field);

        };

        scope.save = function(index){
            console.log(scope.form);
            scope.editMode[index] = false;              

            if (scope.editing !== false ) {     
                //do the saving            
                scope.editing = false;
            } 
        };



        scope.cancel = function(index){
            scope.editMode[index] = false;

            if (scope.editing !== false) {
                scope.source.data[scope.editing] = scope.previousData;
                scope.editing = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there a reason as to why your save function has to be outside the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

[Working Form](http://plnkr.co/edit/WiJL0XzvXtuOuJO2zSgg?p=preview)

- Form button is outside of form, and could also be outside of directive. It doesn't matter with Angularjs.
- There are two inputs, both have required and both have regex validation as you stated.
- There is a directive with a templateURL

The important thing to remember here is that the form must have a name, and then it is referenced by that name as in: scope.myForm when

You don't have to name the input fields as I did in the plunker, but if you do, and they are ALL different values from one another, then you can do this: scope.myForm.myInputName.$valid to see if each input is valid if you wished.

But, the actual form will not be valid until ALL the inputs are valid, so you probably just need to call valid on the form itself as in in the provided example.

If you move the button outside of the directive, you will have to move the submit function from the directive to the controller (most likely).

Let me know if this helps, I can change things if needed. Also, try the plunker first with your question, then post what's going on with that new code; just fork the plunker and provide a link.

Here is the plunker code just in case...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.7" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@0.12.0" data-semver="0.12.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <my-directive></my-directive>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>

<form name="myForm" novalidate>
  <label>Input #1 (required)</label><br>
  <input ng-model="form.data.myName" name='myName' ng-pattern="/\D+/" ng-required="true" /> <span ng-show="myForm.myName.$error.pattern">Takes anything but digits</span><br>
  <br>
  <label>Input #2 (required)</label><br>
  <input ng-model="form.data.myEmail" name='myEmail' ng-pattern="/\d+/" ng-required="true" /> <span ng-show="myForm.myEmail.$error.pattern">Takes only digits</span>
</form>
<br>
<p># I'm a button that is outside of the form!</p>
<p ng-model="form.submitted">Form Submitted: <span class="blue">{{ form.submitted }}</span></p>
<p>Form Valid?: <span class="blue">{{ myForm.$valid }}</span></p>
<button ng-click="submitForm('myForm')">Submit Form</button>

<p ng-model="form.data">Here is the Form data:</p>
{{ form.data }}


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {});

  app.directive("myDirective", function () {

    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      require: '?ngModel',
      templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',

      link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.form = {submitted: false, data: {}};

      scope.submitForm = function(formname){
        console.log(scope[formname].myEmail)
        console.log(scope.formname)
        console.log(scope[formname].$valid)
        scope.form.submitted = true;
      }
    } // end link
  } // end return
});
```